# Stuck in infinite while loop while printing values from a custom linked list

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to implement a basic singly linked list. In that, I am trying to insert from head. Then I tried to print the inserted data. My code is below:

```
 #include<iostream>
 using namespace std;

 template<class T>
 class Node
 {
      public:
      T data;
      Node<T> *next;
      Node():data(T()),next(NULL)
      {}
 };

template<class T>
class SinglyinkedList
{
      public:
      Node<T> *head;
      SinglyinkedList():head(NULL)
      {}
      void insertFromHead(T data)
      {
          Node<T> *temp;
          temp->data = data;
          temp->next = head;
          head = temp;
      }
      void printLinkedist()
      {
           Node<T> *temp;
           temp = head;

           while(temp != NULL)
           {
               cout <<"Hi";
               cout << temp->data;
               temp = temp->next;
           }
      }
 };

int main()
{
    SinglyinkedList<int> list;
    list.insertFromHead(10);
    list.insertFromHead(20);
    list.insertFromHead(30);
    list.insertFromHead(40);
    list.printLinkedist();
    return 0;
}
```

But When I print linked list it just stuck in while loop and printing same value again and again.
Can anyone help why I am stuck in loop?

Comment: In `insertFromHead`, `temp->data` is accessing an uninitialized pointer and is likely to crash.

Comment: @crashmstr But It should be initialized via the default constructor of Node Class.

Comment: `Node<T> *temp;` is an uninitialized *pointer*. `Node<T> temp;` would be a default constructed `Node<T>`.

Comment: @ crashmstr Oh man, u are genious. Thank u.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linked-list code usually contains one use of `new` for each node, and you forgot yours.
This means that you were using an uninitialised pointer, which is undefined.

Add the missing object:

```
void insertFromHead(T data)
{
    Node<T> *temp = new Node<T>;
    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = head;
    head = temp;
}
```

If you add a constructor to `Node`,

```
Node(const T& d, Node<T>* n): data(d), next(n) {}
```

you can shorten it a bit, too:

```
void insertFromHead(const T& data)
{
    head = new Node<T>(data, head);
}
```

Comment: It works. But in my main function I instantiated SinglyLinkedList in similar manner. SinglyinkedList<int> list; And it works there.

Comment: @DevendraVerma That's not a pointer. If you had `SinglyinkedList<int>* list;` and `list->insertFromHead(10);` you would probably (but not certainly) run into some problems.

Comment: I got it. Thank u so much.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying working with uninitialized object

```
Node<T> *temp;
temp->data = data;
```

You got such kind of undefined behavior.
Just use:

```
void insertFromHead( T data )
{
    Node<T> *temp = new Node<T>();
    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = head;
    head = temp;
}
```

An it will solve your problem

Comment: Worth pointing out that using raw pointers will require a `delete` later, and that ideally this would just be done in the constructor; or even using a smart pointer

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is likely here:

```
      Node<T> *temp;
      temp->data = data;
```

temp is not initialized to anything before you attempt to dereference it